# Why does my calloc fail to zero everything out?

Tags: c, cygwin

I defined the following function, where List is a structure.

```
List * LIST_Create()
{
  List * l = calloc(0, sizeof(List));
  unsigned char * pc = (unsigned char *)l;  
  for(i = 0; i < sizeof(List); i++)
  {
    LOG("LIST","0x%1x ", (unsigned char)*pc);
    pc++;
  }
}
```

When I print out the bytes I get this:

```
LIST: 0xffffffbf 
LIST: 0x1 
LIST: 0x13 
LIST: 0x0 
LIST: 0x1 
LIST: 0x1 
LIST: 0x0 
LIST: 0x0 
LIST: 0x0 
LIST: 0x0 
LIST: 0x0 
LIST: 0x5
```

what's going on? I know it isn't the printing that's the issue, because the code is reading non-zero values too. The only way I can reliably zero out the List structure seems to be to initialise all the members individually. I don't mind, but shouldn't `calloc()` work?

Comment: Yet another reason why the "`malloc(0)` should return a unique nonzero pointer" crowd is on crack... If `calloc` had returned `NULL` the program would have crashed right away and the bug would have been apparent...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You allocated space enough for `0` `List`s:

```
List * l = calloc(0, sizeof(List));
```

Therefore your allocated memory is `0` bytes long.

Answer (score 3):

`calloc(0, sizeof(List))` allocates a 0-length buffer; you're printing random data after a "dummy" pointer created so you can `realloc()` it later.  The parameters to `calloc` are the number of items and the size of a single item; this makes it easier to allocate, say, a vector of 5 `(struct foo)`s.

Answer (score 2):

The manual says:

> ```
>    calloc()  allocates memory for an array of nmemb elements of size bytes
>    each and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  The memory is  set
>    to  zero.  If nmemb or size is 0, then calloc() returns either NULL, or
>    a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free().
> ```

Your function call `List * l = calloc(0, sizeof(List));`

Therefore you have a `0` length memory block's address or `NULL` in `l`.  (Probably you have mixed up with `memset` ?)

Comment: yep. Indeed I sort of got it mixed up with memset().

Answer (score 1):

You're requesting an allocation of zero bytes. The size allocated by [`calloc`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/malloc.3.html) is `nmemb*size`, and you have `nmemb == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `calloc` with 0 elements (no elements). You at least have to pass 1:

```
List* l = calloc(1,sizeof(List));
```